# Img src= of a DIV in a fixed block loads on the homepage but do not loads on another pages

Tags: image, html

I have a fixed header.TPL file that is loaded on every page.

There's a DIV in this .TPL file with IMG `SRC=xxx.png` replacing the TEXT. (*a twitter and facebook icon linking to the twitter page*)

Ok, on the homepage it works well. The DIV is showing on the header with the image linking to the twitter page.

But when I go to another page, the DIV with the image disappear. All other DIVs are in the same way as before, only the DIV with the image has gone.

And if I change the image for a TEXT, it works fine. If I put an image again, the DIV only load on the homepage.

What's happening?

```
<div class="fullWidthBlock headerMenuBlock">
    <div class="fixedWidthBlock">
        <div class="headerMenuWrapper">
            {module name="menu" function="top_menu"}
        </div>
        {extension_point name='modules\main\apps\FrontEnd\IWidgetDisplayer' HTTP_REFERER=$GLOBALS.site_url|cat:$GLOBALS.current_page_uri}

        <div class="socialMenuWrapper">
          <ul class="socialMenu">                                       
                                        <li><a class="twitterMenu" href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img src="modules/theme_iauto_grey/main/_files/icons/twitterblue.png" /></a>
            <li><a class="facebookMenu" href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="modules/theme_iauto_grey/main/_files/icons/facebookblue.png" /></a>
          </ul>  
        </div>

        <div class="loginMenuWrapper">
            {if !$GLOBALS.current_user.logged_in}
                <ul class="loginMenu">
                    <li><a class="loginDialogControl" href='#'>[[Login]]</a></li>
                    <li><span>|</span></li>
                    <li><a href='{$GLOBALS.site_url}/user/registration/'>[[Register]]</a></li>
                                        <li><span>|</span></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="loginDialogWrapper" style="display: none;">
                    {module name="users" function="login" HTTP_REFERER=$GLOBALS.site_url|cat:$GLOBALS.current_page_uri}
                </div>
            {else}
                <div class="userGreeting">
                    <span class="welcomeMessage">
                        [[Welcome]], {$GLOBALS.current_user.user_name}
                    </span>
                    <span class="myAccount">
                        <a href="#">[[My Menu]]</a>
                    </span>
                    <div class="myAccountDialogWrapper" style="display: none;">
                        {module name="menu" function="user_menu"}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/if}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

When the image is inserted by CSS the DIV display the image not only in the homepage, but in every page.